# Gulp to compile the scss files and move the css and css.map files to the parent folder relative to the scss file location

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./project/**/*.scss', '!./project/**/_*/'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
            return file.base;
        }));
});
```

```html
/project  
    --> Module1  
        --> scss  
            --> Test1.scss  
    --> Module2  
        --> scss 
            --> Test2.scss
```

Click here for folder structure

[image]

I have a project with multiple modules. I'm trying to write a gulp task that compiles the sass files and creates css files within each module. I have the following **folder structure and gulpfile**.

The task is currently designed to compile the scss files and create the `css` and `css.map` files in the same location as the scss files.
How can I move them both outside the scss folder, but still inside their respective modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a config file to specify the build location for the files so that they can be generated in a folder of your choice, like so:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');
let gulpUtil = require('gulp-util');
let merge = require('merge-stream');

const CONFIGS = [require('./gulp.module1.config'), require('./gulp.module2.config')];

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    let tasks = CONFIGS.map(config => {
        return gulp.src(config.sass.src)
            .pipe(sass())
            .on('error', error => console.log(error))
            .pipe(rename('app.min.css'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildLocations.css));
    });

    return merge(tasks);
});
```

Config 1:

```
module.exports = {
    app: { baseName: 'module1' },
    sass: {
        src: ['./project/module1/scss/*.scss']
    },
    buildLocations: {
        css: './project/module1/'
    }
}
```

config 2

```
module.exports = {
    app: { baseName: 'module1' },
    sass: {
        src: ['./project/module2/scss/*.scss']
    },
    buildLocations: {
        css: './project/module2/'
    }
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z12cf.png)

UPDATE: If you don't want to write an individual config file you can use the path library to rename it, leaves you with the files on the parent level.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src('./project/**/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(rename(function(file) {
            file.dirname = path.dirname(file.dirname)
            return file;
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./project'))
});
```

Comment: Also see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544503/switch-output-folder-based-on-filename-in-gulp-task/48553076#48553076 If possible the gulp-flatten version is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) is really handy for selecting which directories to include or exclude from the final structure.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var flatten = require("gulp-flatten");

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./project/**/*.scss', '!./project/**/_*/'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))

        // keep one parent directory: "Module1", "Module2"
        // relative to your glob bae, so first after "project"

         .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1}))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('project'));
});
```